# Dialog box positive / negative buttons in different position depending on android version

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've been writing an new app for our company and came across an odd thing. On the test device (running 2.3.x) the alert dialog buttons will always be in the order of:

POSITIVE | NEGATIVE

Yet, when I tested the app on my personal cell (running 4.x) the alert dialog buttons were switched to:

NEGATIVE | POSITIVE

The code is obviously the same.

I don't really want to make different versions. But I could cater for later versions in code, and maybe (although its rubbish) swap the text of the positive and negative buttons... Which would work, I'm guessing, but it's a bit horrible!

The only problem I can foresee, is that our end-users aren't that tech-savvy and having multiple devices, using differing versions of the OS, could cause issues (which I could easily cater for, but would rather some kind of 'standard').

Is this something I can get around? Or is it best to leave as is and let the OS handle it (as I am doing now)? Also, are there any other small issues I'm going to run into. I.e. Can I guarantee that on 4+ devices that if I'm only using 2 buttons that they will remain in the above order.

What I'm hoping someone will post is a hidden flag that magically sets 4.x alert dialogs to 2.x style :) I'm pushing my luck, I know!

Cheers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a standard behavior for `Dialog`. In GingerBread and before, the position will always be `POSITIVE|NEUTRAL|NEGATIVE`, while in HoneyComb and after is `NEGATIVE|NEUTRAL|POSITIVE`. As this is defined by the OS itself, you don't really have to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting piece of lunacy from Google ([see issue 24138](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24138)) but, as of ICS, this is how it's supposed to be. Definitely best to let the OS choose the ordering.

Comment: Cheers. I too thought it was slightly odd. I've been developing the app for a wee while, and am so used to what buttons are where and the first couple of tries on 4.x the dialog kept cancelling. Took me a few goes to figure that one out. As long as it stays the same from here on, I'll just switch them for older OS. It's not ideal, but I need the consistency. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have it the same for all versions, you could potentially check which version of Android is being run, and change the negative/positive buttons yourself. I don't recommend it, and people will expect it to like it is on their device, don't shoehorn everyone into having the exact same flow.

Comment: It's for a company only app. We have two possible devices. One being a barcode scanner 2.3 and the other a tablet 4.x - I don't mind 'shoehorning' as its internal use only and not going to a mass market, so it may be easier to fudge the buttons myself, just to give it the same look and feel. Just annoying and odd really.